# Assign UserId to my child entity results in a 2n UserId1 column in the sql table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am using

```
asp.net core 
asp.net core identity 
entity framework core
```

My User entity has a child navigation property 'Projects' because a User can have many Projects and a Project entity has one User navigation property:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

When I update my database with the migrations then in the Project sql table a column UserId is created which is also the foreign key to User.Id.

That happend all automatically by convention.

But when I want to save a new project with the related userId

```
context.Projects.Add(project);
project.User.Id = userId; // User is null here
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I just get an exception. I can also write:

```
project.User = new User{ Id = userId };
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

How can store that project entity with just that userId without retrieving the whole user again?

P.S. When I create an additional UserId property in the project entity then another UserId column is created in the sql table with the name 'UserId1'.

UPDATE

```
public class Project
{ 

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}

 modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasOne(x => x.User).WithMany(p => p.Projects).IsRequired();
```

Comment: *I just get an exception* What is the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. If you use your code in this order:

```
context.Projects.Add(project);
project.User = new User{ Id = userId };
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

... you only have to add one more line:

```
context.Projects.Add(project);
project.User = new User{ Id = userId };

context.Attach(project.User);

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Now Entity Framework knows that the user is an existing user and it will use its `ID` as foreign key for `project`. In this case, `project.User` is a so-called *stub entitiy*: an incomplete entity object that's used to avoid a roundtrip to the database.

As an alternative, you can add a property `UserId` to `Project`, which will be picked up by EF as foreign key belonging to `Project.User`.

Comment: Thanks the attach worked. I also tried as I said before to add the UserId to the project entity but then I have a UserId AND a UserId1 column in my project table...

Comment: Do you have any explicit mapping (fluent mapping)?

Comment: No, that was what I checked first, but there is nothing about a UserId. The only thing I changed in the fluent after that UserId1 thingie was to make the navigation property User Not Null via:             modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasOne(x => x.User).WithMany(p => p.Projects).IsRequired(); because by default the UserId was nullable in the database in my project table.

Comment: The problem is that there *is* nothing about a UserId. You have to add `.HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId)`.

Comment: No... I mean the ForeignKey was just added automatically by adding the User property to the Project entity.

Comment: What I meant to say is that *if* you add a mapping (`modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasOne....`) it must also contain `.HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId)`. If EF adds a column `UserId1` there seems to be some other reference to `User` from `Project`. You should show the classes to get that sorted out.

Comment: Before I had the modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasOne stuff EF created the Foreign key for me afair due to conventional naming: Project.User to User.Id. But yes I update my question now with the classes.